# How inner join then left join with group by in linq

Tags: sql, linq

Here is my sql query.
I want to do two join then group by
and convert this sql query to linq

please help anyone.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT  d.acc_id, 
    com.[nrt_account],
    com.name, 
    sum([dr_amount]) as debit,
    SUM(cr_amount)as credit,
    CAST(dr_time as DATE) as date
        
    
  FROM [FRD].[dbo].[debit_entry] d  inner join [FRD].[dbo].[credit_entry]  c
  on d.acc_id = c.acc_id
  left join [FRD].[dbo].company  com on c.acc_id = com.acc_id
   
  GROUP BY CAST(dr_time AS DATE) ,  
  com.[nrt_account] ,
  com.name,
  d.acc_id
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: What you have tried so far? It is easy LINQ expression.